# Do the Q Exist In the Abrams Star Trek Universe?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009, star-trek-q, star-trek-into-darkness, star-trek-beyond

In the Abrams Star Trek universe, do the Q exist? Any reference to them in or out of universe? Any novelizations, comics, commentaries, or quotes from Abrams or writers about them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The (canon-ish) IDW Star Trek Ongoing comic series *[The Q Gambit](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/The_Q_Gambit)* featured Q meeting the crew of the "Alternate Universe" Enterprise.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: it's not a terrible story, but if it is indeed canon, it needs a big reset button

Comment: @NKCampbell - I'm incredibly dubious about their claim of canonicity. Any future films will undoubtedly ignore whatever nonsense happened in the comics.

Comment: Considering kurtzmans picard contradicted kurtzmans countdown comic any jj-verse expanded material is trivia even relative to their own dubious canon.

Comment: I find it amusing that even Q refers to JJ plot devices as a "whatever it was".  That unintentionally says a lot about the Q-uality of writing.

Comment: John D Lancie was SO masterful with that role

Answer (score 0):

As the Kelvin Timeline is just an offshoot of the Prime Timeline shortly before the Kirk era, Q would absolutely exist and be more familiar with it than anyone. They're eternal beings who've been around for millenia or longer. So they existed long before the two timelines branched.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back up this bold statement?

Comment: You want evidence that the Kelvin Timeline is an offshoot of the Prime Timeline? Like, watch the 2009 movie. It's kinda the plot.

Comment: So you evidence is *"watch the film"*? How does that provide any evidence that Q exists there?

Comment: I'm not sure what more you would need. The movie starts at the divergence point between the Prime Timeline and the Kelvin Timeline. The new timeline's history prior to that is just the Prime Timeline. Which we know Q has existed in as far back as Woodstock bare minimum. The real question is, why *wouldn't* he be there?

Comment: For starters, it's been established that the temporal "ripples" extend far earlier than the event that caused the divergent timelines.

Comment: That's not really established. That's a Simon Pegg quote trying to explain why Sulu was now gay. (Something he didn't really need to do.) Not something from the narrative or official source. It's an even bigger leap to suggest that a ripple in time erased the Q from existence.