# Is there anywhere that the Q is not?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-q

Related: [Do the Q Exist In the Abrams Star Trek Universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/245940/70477)

In an answer to the question above, it is established that Q is present in the Abramsverse. Is there *anywhere* that the Q is not? That is, is it ever established that there is a place in the universe or multiverse that the Q has either never been to or is unable to visit?

The Q are clearly described as omnipotent or at least nearly omnipotent with respect to the regular Star Trek galaxy, so Q can presumably catch the vapors of Aldebaran, blow up Ferengi trading ships, or tour pre-classical Andoria at his pleasure. Is it fair to extrapolate that there are no places, dimensions, rifts, anomalies, etc. that are truly off-limits to the Q?

Comment: *"Nothing left to explore"* - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zp9cL458Qns

Comment: Gödel's incompleteness theorems apply here.  Even if one episode said yes they can go everywhere- there's nothing to stop another from inventing something bigger they can't access.

Comment: @lucasbachmann If Gödel wants a say on _Star Trek_ canon, he can submit a spec script like anyone else.

Comment: @lucasbachmann I do not think that Star Trek is an axiomatic formal system with omega-consistency, so I don't see how these theorems can possibly apply, even though it is certainly fashionable to refer to Gödel wherever it seems remotely reasonable to establish a connection.

Comment: I wish the writers gave us episodes where Q says hello to Nagilum, the Edo god, and Armus.

Comment: In the EU novels and comics the Q are far less omnipotent. There's a bunch of places that they can't go including the M-Continuum, the Omega Continuum, The Temple of the Pah Wraiths, before the beginning of the universe, etc etc